# 20.04 - External HD shows up in Disks but does not open

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a Seagate 2 TB disk that worked well with Ubuntu and Windows.

Recently, after some data transfer, an attempt to safely remove the disk was stopped with an error: "**an operation is already pending**".

I restarted the PC (in hindsight, probably a mistake) and tried connecting the disk again.
Now the disk is getting detected in **Disks**, but causes **Disks** to hang.
It also shows up in the File Explorer, but I'm unable to open it from there as well. The disk lights up as it would normally.

It takes slightly longer (about 10 seconds more) to show up in the File Explorer.

[The Seagate shows up in **Disks**, on the left. But then **Disks** freezes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWlF.png)

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab26 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Slim Portable Drive 1 TB
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56b2 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Partial output of `dmesg`

```
  262.468843] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  262.489944] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab26, bcdDevice= 1.08
[  262.489949] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  262.489952] usb 2-3: Product: BUP Slim BL
[  262.489954] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  262.489956] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: NA97SR1C
[  262.512222] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  262.517535] scsi host2: uas
[  262.517765] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  262.518160] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BL      0108 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  262.519299] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  296.200282] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  297.259479] .ready
[  297.260316] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[  297.260319] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  297.260504] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  297.260507] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[  297.260853] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  297.261178] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[  297.286718]  sdb: sdb1
[  297.288946] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  341.333378] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[  341.333385] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 34 c6 47 40 00 00 08 00
[  341.345456] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  341.474068] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  341.495235] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  502.083042] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=191s
[  502.083096] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  502.083101] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  502.083108] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 34 c6 47 40 00 00 08 00
[  502.083114] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 885409600 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  592.456646] scsi host2: uas_pre_reset: timed out
[  592.456825] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  592.456832] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 34 c6 47 40 00 00 08 00
[  592.456895] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=90s
[  592.456898] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 34 c6 47 40 00 00 08 00
[  592.456903] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 885409600 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  592.456910] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 110675944, async page read
[  592.457628] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6139584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[  592.457662] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6139584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  592.457666] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 767192, async page read
[  592.457860] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6139584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  592.457866] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 767192, async page read
[  592.462453] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  592.720632] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Comment: Seagate external drives are notorious for its unreliability. The drive itself not very good (it's Seagate) but the worse is the SATA-USB "converter". I've seen those fail by the dozens some years ago, lesson learned. The symptom you described suggests exactly the same problem. The drive inside may or may not still be usable on a new enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late update, but @ChanganAuto was on the money. The drive failed completely and the data was lost.
I guess there are ways to retrieve that data, but it wasn't anything I would miss.
I'll get a drive from another brand next time.